# Using a shell script: How to get the icon name (or path) of an open window in X-based window manager?

Tags: shell, xorg, xdg

I am able to get window ids and window titles using `wmctrl`, but so far I haven't been able to get the path to the icon used by the window.  I've tried looking at xdg utilities, but the closest was installing/uninstalling icons.

Is there a way to get the name of the icon used by XDG/GTK or  the  dir path to the icon in a shell script/command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get it from `wmctrl` because it only knows about window properties.  None of the icon-related properties in [Extended Window Manager Hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) tell *where* an icon resides.  That is because it could be an in-memory pixmap (as xterm does for certain configurations since [patch #282](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282)).

Presumably you already know about these properties:

- [_NET_WM_ICON_NAME](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472639104)
- [_NET_WM_VISIBLE_ICON_NAME](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472637280)
- [_NET_WM_ICON](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472568384)

But that is only a starting point.  Assuming that there is an icon file, you would have to look for it in the directory tree where icons live, e.g., `/usr/share/pixmaps`, according to the current *theme*.

A similar question was asked in [What's the absolute path of an icon declared in a .desktop file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66396/whats-the-absolute-path-of-an-icon-declared-in-a-desktop-file), which points to

- [Icon Theme Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#icon_lookup) (giving directory layout and pseudocode)
- [How can I get the full file path of an icon name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090241/how-can-i-get-the-full-file-path-of-an-icon-name) (with an answer in the form of a python script).

Getting the *theme* name is desktop-dependent.  A related question (and answer) is found in [desktop agnostic icon theme lookup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208234/desktop-agnostic-icon-theme-lookup)

Comment: So if I am interpreting this correctly, applications usually provide pixmap data that is then used by EWMH-compliant software to display to the screen? (Thanks for taking the time to provide a detailed answer.)

Comment: A little too simplified: most of the applications you are interest in will load files from the `pixmaps` directory-tree.  But there is no guarantee that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

So instead of the name, you can get the image itself:

```
xprop -id THE_WINDOW_ID -notype 32c _NET_WM_ICON |
   perl -0777 -pe '@_=/\d+/g;
   printf "P7\nWIDTH %d\nHEIGHT %d\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n", splice@_,0,2;
   $_=pack "N*", @_;
   s/(.)(...)/$2$1/gs' > icon.pam
```

You can pipe that ouput to `pamrgbatopng` (from `netpbm`) to get a PNG image:

```
xprop -id THE_WINDOW_ID ... | perl -0777  ... | pamrgbatopng > the_icon.png
```

It's hacky, kinda slow, but it's something.

Credits: 
This is a combination of @[Thomas Dickey](https://superuser.com/questions/1017454/using-a-shell-script-how-to-get-the-icon-name-or-path-of-an-open-window-in-x#1017462)'s answer with  [How to dump the icon of a running X program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48860/how-to-dump-the-icon-of-a-running-x-program.